# How to add legend to geom_smooth in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, spline

Have a problem of adding legend to different smooth in ggplot.

```
    library(splines)
    library(ggplot2)
    temp <- data.frame(x = rnorm(200, 20, 15), y = rnorm(200, 30, 8))

    ggplot(data = temp, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + 
      geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y ~ bs(x, df=5, intercept = T), col='blue') + 
      geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y ~ ns(x, df=2, intercept = T), col='red')
```

I have two splines: red and blue. How I can add a legend for them?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Put the colour in `aes()` and add `scale_colour_manual()`:

```
ggplot(data = temp, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y ~ bs(x, df=5, intercept = T), aes(colour="A")) + 
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y ~ ns(x, df=2, intercept = T), aes(colour="B")) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="legend", values=c("blue", "red"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Very beautiful solution!

Comment: And of course you can use the labels property in the scale_colour_manual to change the label of A and B.

Comment: The fill colour in the legend gets darkened and takes the colour that is displayed when the two confidence intervals intersect. Is there a way to prevent such a behaviour from happening ?

Comment: @Rphad I don't have an answer to your question. If it has not been asked already elsewhere on SO you may ask a new question to get more attention.

Comment: @beetroot I actually did and got an answer! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64359233/