# Mixed fill color in ggplot2 legend using geom_smooth() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill, confidence-interval

When plotting two regression curves using `geom_smooth()` in `ggplot2`, for the `fill` color, the legend picks the one where the confidence intervals intersect. I do think this behaviour arises when the overlapping area is proportionally bigger that the other, however I find this quite undesired because the reader is capable of deducing that the "darkened" area is the one where the CI intersect. It is IMHO a bit harder or unintuitive to assign the same color for both the curves.

How can I correct this ?

**MWE:**

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length)) + geom_point()
p <- p + geom_smooth(method=loess, aes(colour="Loess"), fill="yellow")
p <- p + geom_smooth(method=lm, aes(colour="LM"))

print(p)
```

**Output:**

[image: The data and colors used here are used for illustration purposes only]

Comment: What you want is the same color for both shades?

Comment: No, I want the legend to show a grey background next to LM and a yellow background next to Loess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the fill as an aesthetic mapping, ensuring you name it the same as the color mapping to get legends to merge:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = "data")) +
  geom_smooth(method=loess, aes(colour="Loess", fill="Loess")) +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, aes(colour="LM", fill = "LM")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow", "gray"), name = "model")  +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue"), name = "model") +
  labs(shape = "")
```

[image]

Comment: You defeated me by seconds. That deserves +1 As always you are awesome!

Comment: Damn simple. Thanks. Any idea on why it isn't the default behaviour ?

Comment: What if I want to add a legend for the points too ? Ideally to obtain "Model : -LM -Loess" and "Data: -points". I feel like this answer makes it harder to achieve

Comment: Not at all @Rphad -  you could add a shape, size or alpha scale to do that. I'll update to demonstrate

Comment: I was trying with colour inside aes() for coloured data points but this works well. Thanks again !